# Specifying an S3 bucket when deploying a cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to deploy a cloudformation template using a command that looks as follows:

```sh
aws cloudformation deploy \
        --stack-name stackname \
        --template-file folder/file.yaml \
        --s3-bucket bucketname \
        --s3-prefix prefix
```

The error that I receive is:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation:
> S3 error: **The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.**
> For more information check
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

I have checked the link to try and understand what is being asked of me, but it seems to relate to directly using S3, and not using S3 via CloudFormation.

I can't determine a way to do what it is asking using the available parameters of `aws cloudformation`

Comment: can you try bucket name with endpoint 

<bucketname>.s3-<region>.amazonaws.com

Comment: What's in your template `file.yaml`? I think the error maybe due its content, not the command. Command seems fine.

Comment: have you defined a region?

Comment: @Ashwini when I do that it says the bucket does not exist

Comment: @Marcin the content is deploying some EC2, NLBs, target groups..... nothing to do with S3. Also the template hasn't changed radically in months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template file that defines a stack must be in an Amazon S3 bucket that is in the **same region** as the AWS CloudFormation stack being created.

Comment: Is this something that changed in the last week? I've been deploying to 7 different regions with a bucket in us-east-1 for over a year

Comment: It has always been a requirement -- at least when specifying a bucket via the CloudFormation console.

Comment: I don't understand how this is even possible because I have been doing the same deployment process for longer than a year. This makes so little sense to me that I am at boiling point, but I've marked this as the answer because deploying our us-east-1 stack worked.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with how the bucket is being referenced? eg `bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` vs `bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`? I think the first one is a 'generic' format. Something might have changed there, given that S3 bucket paths are being changed.

Comment: s3 is not a regional service.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven Amazon S3 _is_ a regional service. It presents itself as a global service in the management console, and S3 buckets can be referenced from any region, but it is implemented as a Regional Service. For example, each bucket resides in a single region.

Comment: Please show the url you used (xxx out the sensitive info) I am struggling with this...

Answer (score 2):

```sh
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name myteststack --template-file folder/file.yaml --s3-bucket bucketname --s3-prefix prefix --region us-east-1
```

You may replace the parameter and try this.
You need not to pass the region for s3 bucket nor endpoint is required. Yes, if the Bucket and Cloudformation are in a different region in such cases you may face an issue. But I'm sure it will be access denied issue, not something that you have mentioned here.