# S3 error: Access Denied when deploying CFN template with Nested Stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to launch a CFN templated, Nested Stack.  The child stack is in a bucket in the same region as the parent I am trying to launch via CFN console.

I have Administrator Access and am able to create the resources via a single CFN template, but for some reason, when using nested stacks the follow error is returned:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [My-Sns-Stack]. . Rollback requested by user.
My-Sns-Stack    CREATE_FAILED   S3 error: Access Denied For more information check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html
```

I've checked the following resources, but doesn't resolve the issue:

[Specifying an S3 bucket when deploying a cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548918/specifying-an-s3-bucket-when-deploying-a-cloudformation-template)

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/bjk3qw/cloudformation_nested_stacks_s3_access/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html

```
...
    Resources:
        SnsStack:
            Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
            Properties:
                TemplateURL: !Ref SnsStackUrl
                TimeoutInMinutes: 15
...
```

Comment: Are there any bucket policies? Are you deploying the template with custom CloudFormation role, or using instance role?

Comment: No bucket policies, default. I've tried deploying with a custom IAM role for CFN (Administrator access), AND also without a role (I have Administrator access), so it should assume my permissions.

Comment: @Marcin I do have bucket policies inside nested stack, using gh action that assumes role, which has permission though but still gets AccessDenied

Comment: Ok, this happened since the template was old and trying to use a public policy on a bucket without the block set to off which is enforced since 2022 [ref](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/amazon-s3-automatically-enable-block-public-access-disable-access-control-lists-buckets-april-2023/)

Answer (score 24):

I found this error less than useful as I assumed it was to with the CloudFormation template not having access to the S3 resources referenced within in. Turns out it was more simple and the 'Access Denied' error was actually indicating the S3 file containing my CloudFormation template was not found. Within the reference to my nested CloudFormation stack, the TemplateURL: had a typo.

Comment: You saved me! I had a bad reference with a multi-stack CFN deployment, specially the TemplateURL variable that uses S3.

Comment: Thank you for saving me from a few hours of frustration and a possible skull fracture :)

Comment: Thanks it was helpful. I had a file extension typo `yaml` instead of `yml`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above answers, please ensure that the role we're using for the deployment is having the S3 access permission to that S3 or template S3 URL(in case of nested stacks) our Cloud formation yml(template code) is referring to.